# Java SQL Object Oriented Approach to Tables

Tags: java, sql, performance, join

I have a DatabaseObject in Java which can dynamically retrieve information from a database and store it in key-value pairs (it is just an extended LinkedHashMap).

My DatabaseObject can load, delete, update, and insert values into a table, based on provided columns that match the database table.

I have a "Company" table and a "Category" table in my database, and each company can have multiple categories. I also have a "CompanyCategories" table where each company's category is recorded. These are what the tables look like:

```
Company
CompanyID, Name

Category
CategoryID, Name

CompanyCategories
CompanyCategoryID, CompanyID, CategoryID
```

In SQL, I normally will apply a simple join with group concatentation to get a row that looks like this:

```
CompanyID, Name, Categories
1, Dummy Company, Photographer;Videographer
```

I am trying to figure out how to best pull this information into a Company object in Java that contains references to another Category object. In my view, I'm not pulling the CategoryID or the CompanyCategoryID, but I will need those if I delete a category from a company, since it's in a separate table.

My question is would it be better to execute several SQL statements back to back? In other words:

```
SELECT  * FROM company WHERE CompanyID=1; SELECT * FROM category WHERE CompanyID=1;
```

And then in Java combine them into a Company object with a List of Category objects, or should I let the database do the joining and just include a lot of extra information in my view?

```
SELECT * from company_view
CompanyID, Name, CompanyCategoryIDs, CategoryIDs, Categories
1, Dummy Company, 4;6, 2;3, Photographer;Videographer
```

My problem with the later is that it's going to quickly become problematic to keep straight, while I'm worried about performance with the former. For a single company, it's not going to be a big deal, but 2000-4000 companies could be loaded at any one time.

I really like the object oriented approach I'm taking to dealing with my database tables, but I'm not sure how best to deal with views.

Which would be more efficient?

Comment: Is there any reason you are rolling your own ORM when others already exist like Hibernate?

Comment: Yes, the core Database/DatabaseObject library that I've built is meant to run on desktop applications and Codename One projects, therefore I can't use third-party libraries. Though I've never heard of Hibernate, I'll check it out and see what their approach is